# What is a good place to ask people to criticize my OOP model?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a certain task at hand and have designed an OOP structure to address it. However I am not sure if this structure is going to be super clear to other developers and will stand the test of time or whether it's going to be super confusing, overcomplicated and will just deteriorate once people start using it.

So I wanted to to put it up on Stack Overflow and ask people to criticize it however in the past a bunch of my questions were closed because they were too subjective and opinion based and I feel this one might be one of them. So my question here is whether Stack Overflow is a good place to ask people to criticize OOP structure and if not, what other place can you recommend me for these purposes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question belongs on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

From their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Best practices and design pattern usage

It has to be `working piece of code` though.

If you don't have anything working yet, try [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/):

From their [Help Center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> software architecture and design

Comment: Codereview looks great, I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Not sure you are right about that. You don't seem to be part of that community, and I believe it is for review of working code, not design.

Comment: Just saying - if you are not someone that has been part of a Stack Exchange site, at least read their help center on-topic and off-topic pages before directing people there. For instance, this could be on-topic on [programmers.se], depending on the question (I would also link to the help center documents of the site you are recommending).

Comment: It does now, @PatrickHofman, it does now ;) My point were mostly for the OP here.

Comment: @Oded I think there is a question at Programmers meta focusing on that: [Design Review: on-topic or not?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6502/31260)